# Integrating the product of an exponential and a derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, integrating-factor

I have the following problem that I'm unsure how to tackle:

$\frac{dm}{dt} = \frac{dn}{dt} - \lambda m$

I tried using the integrating factor method with IF = $e^{\lambda t}$ so I end up with:

$me^{\lambda t} = \int{\frac{dn}{dt}e^{\lambda t} dt}$

However, I'm not sure how to progress with this integral? Can anyone help, please?

Thanks.

edit: $\lambda = constant$

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a function of $t$ or a constant?

Comment: $\lambda$ is constant. Edited the post to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel out the $dt’s$. $$\int \frac{dn}{dt} e^{\lambda t} dt = \int e^{\lambda t} dn = ne^{\lambda t} + C $$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! I was playing about with this idea but I'm not confident that it works for this problem:

For example if we take $\dot{x} = t^2$ then $x = 2t$

And
$int{\dot{x}e^{t} dt} = \int{e^{t}dx} = xe^{\lambda t} + C = 2te^{t} + C$

But $\int{t^{2}e^{\lambda t} dt} = 2te^{t} + 2e^{t} + C$

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: My bad! Was rushing when writing this out.

The issue is still there though isnt it?

$\int{\dot{x}e^{t} dt} = \int{e^{t} dx} = t^{2}e^{t} + c \neq \int{2te^{t} dt} = 2te^{t} - 2e^{t} + c$

Comment: Also, how did you format the equation so nicely? Thanks again.

Comment: @Ponder Sorry, are $n$ and $m$ dependent on $t$? In the  example you provided , $x$ is a function of $t$ and it should really go like this: $$\int \dot x e^t dt = \int e^t dx = \int e^t d(t^2) = \int e^t \cdot 2t dt$$ You can use double dollar signs for display-style formatting.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This part makes sense now. Yes both m,n are functions of time. So to solve this integral I need to know what the function $\frac{dn}{dt}$ is equal to in order to substitute this back into the integral.